# Kendo UI Angular Line Charts Fill Data Points

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-chart

I am using Kendo UI Line Chart with Angular. Does anyone know how to make the markers on the Line Chart solid? I receive the line color from the server.

[image: Component template]

I read that I can use `markers: { background: "#004990" },` but this is not a dynamic color from the server.

[image: JSON Result]

This is my code:

```
 this.reportWidgetSubscription = this.reportWidgetService.getChartChartByFilter(serverSide.serverUrl, serverSide.parameters.reportId, serverSide.parameters.chartId, QR).subscribe((data) => {
        let dataResult = data.result;
        if(dataResult){
          serverSide.dataSource = groupBy(dataResult, [{ field: "serieName" }]);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the markers background color just like any other property - the value can come from the respective series item or from a component class field, e.g.:

```
<kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series"
                    [markers]="{ background: item.markerBackground }"
                    type="line" style="smooth" [data]="item.data" [name]="item.name">
                </kendo-chart-series-item>

public series: any[] = [{
    name: "India",
    data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848, 9.284, 9.263, 9.801, 3.890, 8.238, 9.552, 6.855],
    markerBackground: "red"
  }, {...
```

[EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/SgDpkFnjObJ0we6Sv5Hy?p=preview)

If the colors are retrieved from the server separately from the data, you can still bind them in a similar fashion:

[EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/fgRU5c8hhfB4l5tBn4IE?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you @topalkata !!!. I just added this line [markers]="{ background: item.items[i].serieColor }" and everything is working.